# multiple threads using same value fetched by database DAO class method

Tags: java, database, multithreading, postgresql, concurrency

**`Status: solved`**

I had to make a pastebin as I had to point out line numbers.

**note:** not using executorsService or thread pools. just to understand that what is wrong in starting and using threads this way. **If I use 1 thread. the app works Perfect!**

related links:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html

`main app,` http://pastebin.com/i9rVyari
`logs`, http://pastebin.com/2c4pU1K8 , http://pastebin.com/2S3301gD

I am starting many threads (10) in  a for loop with instantiating a `runnable` class but it seems I am getting same result from `db` (I am geting some string from db, then changing it) but with **`each thread, I get same string`** (despite each thread changed it.) . using `jdbc` for `postgresql`     what might be the usual issues ?

```
line 252

and line 223
```

the link is marked as `processed. (true)` in db.  other threads of `crawler class` also do it. so when `line 252` should get a link. it should be `processed = false`.    but I see all `threads take same link.`

when one of the threads crawled the link . it makes it processed = true.   the others then should not crawl it. (get it) is its marked processed = true.

---

`getNonProcessedLinkFromDB()` returns a non processed link

```
public String getNonProcessedLink(){        line 645
public boolean markLinkAsProcesed(String link){   line 705
```

`getNonProcessedLinkFromDB`  will see for processed = false   links and give one out of them .       `limit 1`
**each thread has a starting interval gap of 20 secs.**
within one thread.     1 or 2 seconds (estimate processing time for crawling)

```
line 98  keepS threads from grabbing the same url
```

**if you see the result. one thread made it true. still others access it. waaaay after some time.**

all thread are seperate. even one `races`. the **db makes the link true at the moment the first thread processes it**

Comment: Are you re-using the same database connection?

Comment: I use `new BasicDao().method();`  I have tried to make those methods as `static` too. or put their call in a `sycnhronized block` or make the `boolean` that they return as `volatile` . but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the comments and response by helpers in this post were also correct.

at the start of crawl() method body.

```
    synchronized(Crawler.class){
        url = getNonProcessedLinkFromDB();
        new BasicDAO().markLinkAsProcesed(url);
    }
```

and at the bottom of crawl() method body (when it has done processing):

```
    crawl(nonProcessedLinkFromDB);
```

actually solved the issue.

It was the **gap between marking a link processed true and fetching a new one and letting other threads get the same link while the current was working on it.**

`Synchonized block` helped further.

Thanks to helper. "Fuber" on IRC channels. Quakenet servers #java and Freenode servers ##javaee

and ALL who supported me!

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation of not a concise question being asked. There is lots of code in there and *you* have no idea what is going on. You need to break it down so that you can understand where it is going wrong, then show us that bit.

Some things of potential conflict.

- You are opening a database connections for almost every process. The normal flow of an application is to open a few connections, do some processing, then close them.
- Are you handling database commits? I don't remember what the default setting is for a postres database, you'll have to look into it.
- There are 3 states a single url is in. Unprocessed, being processed, processed. I don't think you are handling the 'being processed' state at all. Because being processed takes time and may fail, you have to account for those situations.

I did not read the logs because they are useless to me.

-edit for comment-
Databases generally have transactions. Modifications you make in one transaction are not seen in other transactions until they are committed. Transaction can be rolled back. You'll need to look into fetching the row you just updated and see if the value has really changed. Do this in another transaction or on another connection.

The gap of 20 seconds looks like it is only when the process is started. Imagine a situation where **Thread1** processes **URL1** and **Thread2** processes **URL2**. They both finish at about the same time. They both look for the next unprocessed URL (say **URL3**). They would both start processing this Url because they don't know another thread has started it. You need one process handing out the Url, possibly a queue is what you'd want to look at.

Logging might be improved if you knew which threads were working on which URLs. You also need a smaller sample size so that you can get your head around what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for responding !!! I have mentions exact line numbers that relate to the issue. The full code is necessary in order to analyse if one wants to. 1. multiple connections wont hurt. thats what DBs are for. 2. what do you mean by db `commits`? you mean postgres uses `cache`? 3 I understood you. but each thread has a gap of 20 seconds at start. it takes about 1 to 5 seconds to crawl a page (process it).

Comment: @MasoodAhmad Try reading about transactions in databases. It is what `commit` and `rollback` is used for. And without knowing how transactions work you wont be able to build multitreaded DB applications (because transactions is a way databases handle concurency)

Comment: Thanks for edit. I have done the same thing you said in logging paste. it shows urls. 2. I got what you described earlier. I even made the link as `processed = true` at the `start` of the `crawl()` just to be sure that it is marked as `processed` even before the processing begins. (that is the thread owns the link and other threads should consider it as processsed) . Still...... same. it is a mistory

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I hope there is not row lock. heres the query. `to mark : update links set processed = ? where href = ?        and     to get : SELECT href from links where processed = false limit 1`

Comment: @MasoodAhmad Postgres generally do not use locks (but can if you want it to). The problem with your `update` - its changes are not seen to other crawlers until a transaction is committed.

Comment: @MasoodAhmad You can explicitly lock the row you are processing to avoid other crawlers getting the same row. Use something like `select ... for update limit 1;` or custom postgres locks.

Comment: Cant see how to have a row lock. have tried `SELECT href from links where processed = false limit 1 for update` but same results –

Comment: tried all in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html     but no use